# Как отслеживать новые товары на сайте?

Tags: node.js, парсер

У меня есть парсер на ситилинк, копирующий все товары на вкладке. Как сделать так, чтобы копировались только новые, только что появившиеся товары? В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: В сторону увеличения id?

Comment: ну или хранить id  базе и сверять.